# Передача из php скрипта в скрипт методом GET

Tags: php, get

Добрый день. Возникла пред до мной задачка такая. Сам себе задал ее, сам и решаю. Нужно передать переменные из одного обработчика в другой, методом GET. При этом, я знаю что переменные определяются в ссылку. Т.е http://test.ru/patch/file.php?var=23&var2=54. И определяю ссылку переменную. Как потом передать переменную с ссылкой в другой скрипт???. Остался небольшой шаг, который мне не дается пока. Надеюсь поможете))

Comment: для передачи - base64 + json в помощь. Если вы хотите получить ответ на ваш вопрос, то раскройте пожалуйста смысл вот этого - "как потом передать переменную с ссылкой"

Comment: >переменные определяются в ссылку
>...
>определяю ссылку переменную

Это вы так про get-запрос? Переформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос, а то ничего не понятно. =)

Comment: Видимо, ТС нужно:

    $url = "http://example.com/?url=".urlencode("http://test.ru/patch/file.php?var=23&var2=54");

Answer (score 1):

Если первый скрипт ничего не выводит, то формировать ссылку и редиректить:

```
$data = array();
$data['code'] = 1;
$data['name'] = 'абвгд';
$url = 'http://site.ru/file.php?' . http_build_query($data);
header('Location: ' . $url);
```